# Strong Markov Property: Having Trouble Understanding Proof Using Strong Markov

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm having trouble understanding this proof of Example 1.4.4 From Norris' Markov Chains: Let $X_n$ be a DTMC, with transition matrix P and state-space $I$. Let $Y_m=X_{T_m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Show $Y_m$ is a DTMC.

Define $$T_0=\inf\{n\geq0:X_n\in J\subset I\}$$ and $$T_{m+1}=\inf\{n> T_{m}:X_n\in J\subset I\}$$

For $i_0,...,i_{m+1} \in J$ we have 
\begin{align*}
&P(Y_{m+1}=i_{m+1}|Y_0=i_0, ..., Y_m=i_m)\\
&=P(X_{T_{m+1}}=i_{m+1}|X_{T_{0}}=i_0,...,X_{T_{m}}
=i_m)\\
&=P(X_{T_{m+1}}=i_{m+1}|X_{T_m}=i_m)\\
&=P(X_{T_{1}}=i_{m+1}|X_{0}=i_m)
\end{align*}

I'm confused by several lines of the proof. Does the **second** equality follow from the fact that $X_n$ is a DTMC and thus by Markov property?
Does the **third** equality follow form the fact that $T_m$ is a stopping time so by Strong Markov Property Markov Chain regenerates at $T_m$ so its like starting from $0$ and hitting for first time. So shouldn't it be $X_{T_{0}}=i_{m+1}$ and not $X_{T_{1}}=i_{m+1}$? (Really confused about this).

Also I don't get how the proof shows that $Y_m$ is a Markov chain. We showed that $P(Y_{m+1}=i_{m+1}|Y_0=i_0, ..., Y_m=i_m)=P(X_{T_{1}}=i_{m+1}|X_{0}=i_m)$. How does this show that $Y_m$ is a Markov chain and has the Markov property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the first equality is the defimition of $Y_0, \ldots, Y_{m+1}$
- the second equality is the strong Markov property ($T_m$ is a stopping time)
- you could write $P(X_{T_1} = i_{m+1} \mid X_{T_0} = i_m)$ instead of $P(X_{T_1} = i_{m+1} \mid X_0 = i_m)$ if you wish; the probabilities are equal (both are the probability that the second visit to $J$ is $i_{m+1}$ given that the first visit to $J$ is at $i_0$).
- You've shown that the probability $P(Y_{m+1} = i_{m+1} \mid Y_0 = i_0, \ldots, Y_m = i_m)$ is a function of $i_{m+1}$ and $i_m$ (and in particular does not depend on $i_0, \ldots, i_{m-1}$), which proves the Markov property.

Comment: So third equality is not Strong Markov Property?

Comment: Also $X_0=i_m$ doesn't imply that first visit to $J$ is at $i_m$? because $X_0$ could be at a state not in J?

Comment: Oh but $i_m$ is in J? Got it. So does the third equality come from restarting of Markov Chain by Strong Markov Property @angryavian? Thanks

Comment: @bobbob Yes, you got it.

Comment: So just to double check third equality follows from Strong Markov as well (in addition to second equality) @angryvivian? thanks